# Why isn't this regex finding a match?

Tags: java, regex

Here's my class I'm in the middle of writing:

```
public class MtomParser {

    private static final String HEADER_REGEX = "^\\s*Content-ID:";

    public boolean isMtom(String payload) {
        return payload.contains("--uuid");
    }

    public String parseMtom(String mtomResponse) {
        while (mtomResponse.matches(HEADER_REGEX)) {
            System.out.println("header found");
        }
        return mtomResponse;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting my input to make this code cause an infinite loop since it should find a match and there's no way to escape the loop.  But, `mtomResponse.matches(HEADER_REGEX)` returns false every time and I'm not sure why.  Here's the `mtomResponse`:

```
--uuid:b6bd1ef2-63e2-4d8d-8bac-eabbe7588373
        Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="application/soap+xml";
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
        Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Header/><soap:Body><RetrieveDocumentSetResponse xmlns="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007" xmlns:ns10="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:ns11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" xmlns:ns12="urn:gov:hhs:fha:nhinc:common:subscriptionb2overridefordocuments" xmlns:ns13="http://nhinc.services.com/schema/auditmessage" xmlns:ns14="urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:EDXL:DE:1.0" xmlns:ns15="http://www.hhs.gov/healthit/nhin/cdc" xmlns:ns16="urn:gov:hhs:fha:nhinc:common:subscriptionb2overrideforcdc" xmlns:ns2="urn:gov:hhs:fha:nhinc:common:nhinccommon" xmlns:ns3="urn:gov:hhs:fha:nhinc:common:nhinccommonentity" xmlns:ns4="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" xmlns:ns5="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0" xmlns:ns6="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0" xmlns:ns7="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:lcm:3.0" xmlns:ns8="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:ns9="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><ns5:RegistryResponse status="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:ResponseStatusType:Success"/><DocumentResponse><HomeCommunityId>urn:oid:422.422</HomeCommunityId><RepositoryUniqueId>422.422</RepositoryUniqueId><DocumentUniqueId>422.422^C4n2hv7z_5Ofa37W</DocumentUniqueId><mimeType>text/xml</mimeType><Document><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:3511c0cc-5e20-46b7-8ae0-406c3b1ea95f-6@urn%3Aihe%3Aiti%3Axds-b%3A2007"/></Document></DocumentResponse></RetrieveDocumentSetResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
        --uuid:b6bd1ef2-63e2-4d8d-8bac-eabbe7588373
        Content-Type: text/xml
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
        Content-ID: <3511c0cc-5e20-46b7-8ae0-406c3b1ea95f-6@urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007>

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 http://hit-testing.nist.gov:11080/hitspValidation/schema/cdar2c32/infrastructure/cda/C32_CDA.xsd">
<realmCode code="US"/>
<typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040"/>
```

In my IDE, if I search by the regex of `^\s*Content-ID:`, it finds 2 results.  So why doesn't this java code find any matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable MULTILINE mode, to allow `^` to match each line instead of the entire string.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(yourRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Yes, that fixed my issue.  I don't know how I've never run into this issue before... Why does `find()` work but `matches()` doesn't?

Comment: The `String.matches()` is a convenience method and doesn't use MULTILINE mode. It would have been good if they'd included another method with the flags as a parameter. But they didn't, so you have to do it the long way :)